# Simple 2d Java game issue

Tags: java, sprite

This seems like an easy-fix however I just can't seem to get it, xMove represent moving on the x-axis, y for the y-axis. Currently while my player object is colliding downwards with a tile (standing on the ground) the sprite will be facing right. I want my player to face left if I have been moving left just before that. So basically I need a way to remember what way my character is facing and return that to the yMove == 0 part of my code. Could anyone give me any advice?

```
private BufferedImage getCurrentAnimationFrame(){ //set Player animations when moving


    if(xMove > 0){
        facingRight = true;
        facingLeft = false;
        return animRight.getCurrentFrame();

    }
    if(xMove < 0){
        facingLeft = true;
        facingRight = false;
        return animLeft.getCurrentFrame();
    }
    if(yMove > 0){
        return Assets.playerFall;
    }

    if(yMove < 0){
        return Assets.playerFall;
    }
    if(yMove == 0){
        return Assets.playerFacingRight;
    }

        return null;
}
```

Edit: I tried messing around with booleans to return different sprites e.g. if(facing Left){return Assets.playerFacingLeft} however doing this somehow doesn't return an image at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rearrange your code: Handle the y-axis movement first. If there's no vertical movement, then check horizontal movement.    I added the final `if(facingLeft)` statement to handle the situation when the player is neither falling nor standing still:

```
private BufferedImage getCurrentAnimationFrame(){ //set Player animations when moving

    if(yMove > 0){
        return Assets.playerFall;
    }

    if(yMove < 0){
        return Assets.playerFall;
    }
    if(xMove > 0){
        facingRight = true;
        facingLeft = false;
        return animRight.getCurrentFrame();
    }
    if(xMove < 0){
        facingLeft = true;
        facingRight = false;
        return animLeft.getCurrentFrame();
    }

    if(facingLeft){
        return animLeft.getCurrentFrame();
    } else {
        return animRight.getCurrentFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: After using this code My player Image does not appear when standing still

Comment: Fixed! You don't need to check if `yMove == 0`, if the first two `if` statements false, then `yMove` must necessarily equal zero.

Comment: I added the final `if(facingLeft)` statement to handle the situation when the player is neither falling nor standing still.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you considered x and y axis like this :-

[image]

```
if(xMove > 0){
    facingRight = true;
    facingLeft = false;
    return animRight.getCurrentFrame();

}
if(xMove < 0){
    facingLeft = true;
    facingRight = false;
    return Assets.playerFacingLeft; // here make the player turn left
}
if(yMove > 0){
    return Assets.playerFall
}

if(yMove == 0){
    return Assets.playerFacingRight;
}
if(yMove < 0){
   // fall down or do nothing if you need it to do nothing you can avoid this check or set ymov back to 0
  yMove = 0;
}

    return null;
```

Comment: I basically want my jumping animation and falling animation to be the same, unless java doesn't like this?

Comment: @Alex set yMove to 0 when its less than 0 that way when he tries to go down it resets it to normal 0 position of the y axis

Comment: The problem is: when yMove == 0 it returns playerFacingRight, I want to have my player facing left or right depending on what movement I just did currently while the player is moving left and stops it turns and faces right, I want it to remain facing left

Comment: @Alex please try the edit now, i reordered the if statement to set yMove as 0 after checkeing it

Comment: Hey man, thank you for helping me, the other guy managed to fix my problem though. Cheers anyway!